# How to install meteor router package on Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, meteor

There is a [Meteor router package](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/) that I need installed, but apparently I can't use meteorite, because meteorite doesn't work on windows.

Is there a way to install it in my meteor?

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory called **packages** in your project folder

Example "**/yourproject/packages**"

**Meteor router** needs these three repositories in order to work properly.

Inside the **packages** folder git clone these repositories

**git clone --recursive https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git**

**git clone --recursive https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git**

**git clone --recursive https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git**

remove **meteor** and the folder strutures should look like this inside your **packages** folder

1. **router**
2. **page-js-ie-support**
3. **HTML5-History-API**

then **meteor add router** from your "**/yourproject**" directory

Comment: My package folder has subfolder iron-router, meteor-HTML5-History-API, meteor-page-is-ie-support.   I am getting following errors ... While building package `iron-router`:
error: no such package: 'page-js-ie-support'
error: no such package: 'HTML5-History-API'
error: no such package: 'router'

Answer (score 1):

1. You need create package folder and download the package you want to
       use by using git clone.
2. Some of the packages have dependencies so you need clone those
   packages as well from the git.
3. Make sure you remove meteor from the downloaded directory.
4. Some times, git clone will not download the files completely so you have to go to the package directory where you did not get all the files and run 'git submodule update –init' and then reclone the package.
5. Now that you have all the required packages and changes directory to proper name and all files are available, go back to project root directory and run

> meteor add packagename

Here are some of the references for this
http://csharprambling.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-meteor-package-in-windows/ 
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/using-meteor-and-atmopshere-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply download it to `/yourproject/packages/` folder

Comment: Tried so, but it didn't work. Caused an error called "package page-js-ie-support missing".

Comment: Just get that package too and put it in the packages folder